# Vertical Bar in xsl document() function

Tags: xslt

I need to retrieve a document with parameters using xsl, my code is as following (not real url):

```
<xsl:variable name="stock"
              select="document('http://www.example.com/quote?id=HSI|HK|Index')/GetResponse/Match"/>
```

However the `$stock` returned is empty. I suspect it's the vertical bar | that's causing the problem since | in xsl means or. So I also tried the html entity for the vertical bar, `&#124;` and `&#x7c;`, and to escape the vertical bar using `\`, but none worked. Is there a way to work around this? Thank you so much.

Here's an example of the xml:

```
<NetChange>
<Iso>CALCULATED</Iso>
<Value>2.3696</Value>
</NetChange>
<Volume>195698845</Volume>
<ChangePercent>0.0682868108301452610549793600</ChangePercent>
<IsRealtime>false</IsRealtime>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the XML you expect the `document` function to return? In particular, does it contain namespaces?  Thanks

Comment: @LolaChiang I suspect the vertical bar (`|`) is not the problem, since it is wrapped in quotes so XSL processor should recognize it as literal-string instead of XPath operator

Comment: Your example of the XML is not XML (no closing tag for the `NetChange` root element). Moreover, your `select` statement expects `GetResponse` to be the root element, with a `Match` element as its child. Your XML has none of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way of escaping a vertical bar in a URI is as `%7C`.